# Routing url parameters question: the server responded with a status of 404. Node Express Router

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, url-routing, routeparams, express-router

I'm using Node.js and Express and I'm getting an error that says this:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http://localhost:3000/recentbroadcasts/12-10-2018]**

It was working, and then I tried to add a date parameter to the url and I 
started getting a 404. What am I missing?

Below is the code from the webpage, the app.js and the router file.

I changed the route from **/recentBroadcasts** to **/recentbroadcasts/:dat**e to try and get some info to make a call to my database. Then I started getting the error.

Do I have to do something special to use a route parameter? Thanks

**Route called from webpage Javascript**

```
let getRecentBroadcasts = function (lengthOfBroadcastHistoryNeeded) {

lengthOfBroadcastHistoryNeeded+=7;
let dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded = moment().subtract(lengthOfBroadcastHistoryNeeded, 'days').calendar();
dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded = moment(dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

  fetch('/recentbroadcasts/'+ dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(recentBroadcastsJson => {
      broadcastListData = recentBroadcastsJson;
      populateRecents();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
};
```

**app.js File**

```
let createError = require('http-errors'); 
let express = require('express'); 
let path = require('path'); 
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
let logger = require('morgan'); 
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');


let indexRouter = require('./routes/index'); let usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

let app = express();

app.locals.moment = require('moment');

// view engine setup 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev')); 
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false})); 
app.use(cookieParser()); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Make our db accessible to our router 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {   req.db = db;   next(); });


app.use('/', indexRouter); 
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {   next(createError(404)); });


module.exports = app;
```

**index.js File**

```
let express = require('express');

let router = express.Router();

    router.get('/recentbroadcasts/:date', function (req, res) {  
    let db = req.db;   let collection = db.get('broadcastCollection');   let historyNeeded = req.params.date;   
    let a = moment(historyNeeded);  
    let b = moment().date();      
    let daysOfHistory = a.diff(b, 'days');   
    let dbQuery = { "broadcastAirDate": { $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (daysOfHistory * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))), $lte: new Date((new Date().getTime())) } };   

collection.find(dbQuery, {}, function (e, docs) {
        let sortedBroadcastData = docs.sort(sortDesc("broadcastAirDate"));
        res.json(sortedBroadcastData);   }); });

    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some research, I think I figured out what's happening.
From searching stack overflow, using the tags I tagged my question with, I came up with this:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters
The documentation for the router. Which if I'm reading correctly, basically says that I need a new route parameter after each hyphen.

So the fetch call

```
dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded = moment(dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
fetch('/recentbroadcasts/'+ dateOfLastBroadcastNeeded)
```

needs a router that looks for 3 parameters, like so:

```
router.get('/recentbroadcasts/:month-:date-:year', function (req, res) {
```

I'll try it out, and if it doesn't work, I'll come back here and delete this answer. Otherwise I'll leave this answer for anyone else who comes across this same problem.